# Apache NiFi JoltTransformJSON processor attribute as jolt spec

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a JoltTransformJSON processor.  I want to use the FlowFile attribute (containing the Jolt spec) as the specification.

When I attempt to do it, there is a validation error "JSON Spec provided is not valid JSON format".

I use NiFi 1.6

Is it possible to specify jolt spec as an attribute?
[image: attribute as jolt spec]
[image: validation error]

Answer (score 2):

`Jolt Specification` supports `NiFi Expression Language` but only for substituting the values inside the spec. That is:

Say you have a NiFi attribute : `jolt.operation: shift` you can refer that inside your spec as:

```
[
    {
        "operation" : ${jolt.operation},
        ...
        ...
    }
]
```

The entire spec cannot be sent as a flowfile attribute, at least as of now.